# Prestashop 1.6 Smarty template Error

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with my presta (Prestashop Version 1.6.0.13, php 5.3.29)

When access from the mobile device I get:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/salonsho/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 124
>
> Notice: Undefined index: PTS_SKIN_DEFAULT in /home/salonsho/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 129.....

I guess that is associated with the database....

Which tables in the database are stored information that can be associated with this error?

Thanks in advance
D.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing `Notice: Undefined index: PTS_SKIN_DEFAULT` because you try to get value of `PTS_SKIN_DEFAULT` index while this index is not available in that array.